# Mocha async test failing with undefined AssertError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I am playing around with Mocha for the first time and I'm having difficulty to get a simple test to work.  The call returns before the variable has been assigned and thus comes back as undefined.

Here is the code I would like to test:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
var querystring = require("querystring");

var mongoURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var dbName = process.env.dbName;

//checks for a single email address
var emailAddressExists = function () {
  var returnVal;
  mongodb.connect(mongoURI, function (err, db) {    
    if (err)
      { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }

    var collection = db.collection(dbName); //, function(err, collection) {
    collection.find( { "emailAddress" : "myemail@email.com"} ).count( function (err, count)  {
      if (count == 0) {
        returnVal = false;  
        console.log("not Matched " + returnVal);           
      } else {
        returnVal = true;
        console.log("matched " + returnVal);
      }
      return returnVal;
    });
  });
)
exports.emailAddressExists = emailAddressExists;
```

The test I have is:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    helpers = require ('../lib/helpers.js');

describe('#emailAddressExistsTest()', function() {
  var returnVal;

  it('should return 1 when the value is not present', function(done) {
    assert.equal(true, helpers.emailAddressExists(););
    done();
  });
})
```

When I run 'mocha' I receive the following:

```
#emailAddressExistsTest()
    1) should return 1 when the value is not present


  0 passing (10ms)
  1 failing

  1) #emailAddressExistsTest() should return 1 when the value is not present:
     AssertionError: true == "undefined"
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/emailAddressCheck.js:25:11)
```

Comment: `helpers.emailAddressExists(returnVal);`. It must be crashing here, because `returnVal` is not assigned any value...

Comment: Your function `emailAddressExists` doesn't do anything like what you probably want.  You're going to want to look into callbacks.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar - it shouldn't require returnVal to be initialized and it should be assigned a value from the emailAddressExists call right?

Comment: @AaronDufour I also tried without a parameter and instead sending 'return true' or 'return false' respectively, and calling the assertion with the call directly:
e.g.: in helpers.js:  
    'var returnVal  
    = function emailAddressExists()  
    { ... //return true/false as required  
    }'  

Then in the mocha test file:  
    'assert (true, helpers.emailAddressExists()); '  
  
but I still get undefined. I know it has to do with callbacks, but that's what I'm trying to understand with mocha. How do I run the test so that the call doesn't return before the assignment of the value. Thanks!

Comment: @BobAleena You should focus on figuring out how callbacks work before even worrying about mocha.  You might find that the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) helps.

Comment: @AaronDufour I understand callbacks. Thank you. Perhaps my question is not clear -- What I am trying to understand is, how to test such a function with Mocha.

Comment: @BobAleena Your function doesn't do what you want it to do, to the point that nothing about it is testable.  It does a database read and then throws away the result; it's a no-op.

Comment: @AaronDufour I appreciate your feedback but you are not being helpful and if anything it feels a bit like you are making assumptions -- how exactly do you know 'what you want it to do'??.  The function tests an email address and returns true/false based on the email address existing within the db.  It does not throw away the result - it uses it to check the count and then returns true/false based on that.

Comment: @BobAleena It _does not_ return the result.  It doesn't return anything.  I am trying to be helpful, but for some reason you don't believe me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75533/discussion-between-aaron-dufour-and-bob-aleena).

Comment: Thanks @AaronDufour - the chat has been super helpful. It seems so obvious now!! please post your solution here when you get a chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're going to want to change `emailAddressExists` to take a callback - that's the only way to tell the test when you're done:

```
var emailAddressExists = function (next) {
  mongodb.connect(mongoURI, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    }

    var collection = db.collection(dbName);
    collection.find( { "emailAddress" : "myemail@email.com"} ).count( function (err, count) {
      if (count == 0) {
        next(null, false); 
      } else { 
        next(null, true); 
      } 
      return returnVal;
    });
  });
)
```

Then, you have to pass it a callback and call `done` in the callback:

```
describe('#emailAddressExistsTest()', function() {
  it('should return 1 when the value is not present', function(done) {
    helpers.emailAddressExists(function(err, returnVal) {
      // Maybe do something about `err`?
      assert.equal(true, returnVal);
      done();
    });
  });
})
```

You'll notice that this is a bit different from what we talked about in chat.  The convention in `node.js` is that the first argument to a callback is an error (`null` if no error), and the second argument is the "return value".